# MS Access Form Insertion Hidden value

Tags: ms-access

I'm not really sure how to define this.

I have a table that has a few fields, let's call them: ID, Name, and Type.

I have a form that allows the user to add new records via Datasheet view. ID and Type is hidden, and only Name appears. I've setup a Filter that shows only records of a specific Type (i.e. Type = 2)

However, if someone enters a new record into the datasheet, the Type field does not get set. Setting a default value on the field won't accomplish what I want because I have a few Forms that are tailored based on Type, therefore, each needs to submit new records to the same table based on that type.

Is there a way to define what value it should set Type to? I guess I could capture the BeforeUpdate event, and set the value that way, and just hide the column. I was wondering if there is a way "proper" technique, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form's Before Insert event, you can examine the current Filter expression, parse out the filter's *Type* value, convert it from a string to a number, and finally assign that number to the hidden control which is bound to the *Type* field.

So, assuming that hidden control is a text box named *txtType*, and its control source is a long integer field:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.txtType = CLng(Split(Me.Filter, "=")(1))
End Sub
```

Use the appropriate type conversion function in place of `CLng()` to match the bound field's data type.

That approach *should* work if you're setting the Filter like this:

```
Me.Filter = "[Type] = 2"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

But, if you're using a different method to do the filtering, please give us details about it.